# Best / fasted solution to delete a large number of user data in Symfony / Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working on a `Symfony 2.8` project that allows registered users to manage contacts, documents, appointments, etc.

Now I would like to implement a feature that allows users to reset/delete all their data. So the user account itself should stay intact but all the data entities should be deleted.

Currently I am using a `Doctrine`/`ORM` approach to loop though all entities and delete them:

```
public function deleteAllData($user) {
    $this->currentBatch = 0;
    $this->deleteEntities('MyBundle:Contact', $user);
    $this->deleteEntities('MyBundle:Document', $user);
    ...
    $this->deleteEntities('MyBundle:...', $user);

    $this->flushIfNecessary(true);
}

private function deleteEntities($type, $user) {
   $repo = $this->em->getRepository($type);
   $entities = $repo->findByUser($user);

   foreach ($entities as $entity) {
       $repo->delete($entity);
       $this->flushIfNecessary();
   }
}

private function flushIfNecessary($force = false) {
    $this->currentBatch++;

    if ($force || $this->currentBatch % 100 == 0) {
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->clear();
    }
}
```

While this works fine, it is **very slow**. Using different batch sizes I was able to speed the process up a little bit, but it still takes quite long to delete a large number of entries. Of course this is due to all the `ORM` handling that is done in the background.

**It would be much faster to use simple `SQL` queries:**

```
private function deleteEntities($type, $user) {
   $tableName = null;
   $userId = $user->getId();

   switch ($type) {
       case 'MyBundle:Document':
           $tableName = 'document';
           break;
       ...
   }

   if ($tableName && $userId) {
       $this->em->getConnection()->query("
           DELETE FROM $tableName 
           WHERE user_id = '$userId'
       ");
   }
}
```

This solution works as well, but it require to know the internal DB structure, e.g the table names of the different entities, the name of the `userId` field, etc.

Of course it is not a big deal to get this information but to me this solution seems to be not as clean an the first one.

**Is there a way to get the necessary information from `Doctrine` while still working plain query / bypassing `ORM`?**

Or is there even a better solution to get this done`?

Comment: As per my experience using native queries is the fastest way to delete/update record in doctrine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach is slow because of [object hydration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html#hydration). You don't really need to load all records and transform them into objects. You can simply use [`QueryBuilder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html):

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->delete('MyBundle:Contact', 'c')
   ->where('c.user = :user')
   ->setParameter('user', $user)
   ->getQuery()
   ->execute()
;
```

Or [`DQL`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html):

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
              'DELETE MyBundle:Contact c 
               WHERE c.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user);
$query->execute();
```